# What would happen if every human female turned into a cat?

Tags: society, magic, cataclysms, female

Imagine a future where your sister, mother, grandma, and possibly even yourself have turned into adorable cats.  Science and history have given no apparent hints or evidence that this would have happened (but we can draw connections once in the aftermath), so we are left unprepared for this **cat**astrophe.

However, not everyone is <s>fortunate</s> unfortunate enough to have been turned into a house cat, in fact, with-in hours, males begin to see that only the females are missing from their family, friends, and humanity.

So, as the question entails:

- What are the consequences of a female-less humanity?
- How would the abundance of billions of new cats affect the remaining humans?
- How much more longer would humanity last, or how would we adapt to continue living?

Optionally, you can also answer:

- How did this happen? (For fun, because the focus is the consequences after it happened)

(Perhaps the Ancient Egyptians knew all long)

Remember: we are not only faced with the issue of billions of people missing from humanity, but we now also have billions of cats roaming around in place.

Comment: Apologies if I've mistagged this question, its my first post on World Building.

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to Worldbuilding!  We usually try to have one question per post with follow up if there are additional questions.  Your second and third questions go together, but the others are separate.  Maybe concentrate on just two and three or one of the other questions?

Comment: @Brythan, I removed one of the questions since it was redundant and somewhat implied in the other questions, and the last question is optional for fun since the focus is the consequences of the event and not the cause.  Is that alright?

Comment: "How long will humanity last" in a question which ends all human reproduction is an interesting one to ask.  Are you looking for something more specific than "until this generation dies, because there wont be any more generations?"

Comment: @CortAmmon, I rephrased the question into something what I think would be more Worldbuilding-esque.  "How much more longer would humanity last, or how would we adapt to continue living?"

Comment: As written at 4:30 pm EST on 12/26, I think the question is still too broad.  Limiting it to just one question (like "how long humanity last?") would be the appropriate level of specificity, IMO.

Answer (score 8):

It is the Rapture, of course!

All the caring, kind and noble women of the world have made the cut and been elevated to the heaven of being house cats with families which love (and obey) them.

Judgement day is not without its losers.  Many, many women of bitchier countenance have found themselves damned to the hell of being homeless stray cats.  Scrounging for food and shelter among the hundreds of millions of other soggy, starving and selfish cats; these fallen felines struggle through every day in misery.

In between Heaven and Hell, the men are left in purgatory.  Many are free from the hell-fires of modern relationships, while a few mourn having lost their best friends.  For most, life will go on with only a few changes...

- The Republicans will win the next American Presidential Election.
- The Food Channel will start offering recipes for cooked cat.
- Rats will become an endangered species.

Meanwhile, despite our reputation for being the more war-mongering sex, the men of the world will unite behind a single scientific venture; the quest to bring women back.  Genetic science and artificial womb techniques will race forward, funded by all the money we used to spend on appeasing our women, along with the military budgets of all the world's nations.  There is a simple reason why we will be able to work in such peaceful unity... Our hunger for sex is stronger than our thirst for each other's blood.

Eventually there will be a breakthrough, with a single lab creating the first new female.  The scientists of that lab will become heroes and superstars!  Further refinements will edit out some of the more expensive and non-productive female attributes.  The love of diamonds and shoes will fade into history.  The scientists will be canonized for these accomplishments.  The factories will start pumping out females of every make and model, with websites to handle the ordering process, and surplus military supply planes retrofitted to facilitate delivery.

As the world, smiles with satisfaction and ends its involuntary celibacy, we will unanimously appoint the scientists to be the Kings of our new united, One-World government and live happily ever after.

Comment: Follow up question pending: "I'm a housewife who was turned into a cat, how to I kill my genetically modified replacement in a way that looks like an accident?"

Comment: Why would you kill your replacement?  As the cat of a household that obeys you, isn't she just another slave?  You can never have enough slaves!

Comment: Brilliant. Absolutely brilliant.

Answer (score 2):

**Cats**

You suddenly have a lot of cats that have died, unfortunately - cats in apartments, cats in cars, but some have survived.  Because of the operation of heavy machinery, you might have some men that are killed.

**Population**

There is evidence that a man might, with the assistance of technology [be able to have a baby](http://www.science20.com/challenging_nature/a_real_pregnant_man_almost_certainly_possible_but_it_might_kill_him).  But that means there must be some genetic engineering and tissue transplants and a lot of failures first.  There are enough male scientists, I suspect, to acheive this, but we're talking one or two at a time with intense research.  Your population will begin to drastically decrease.  Also, they will be busy shooing a few cats out of the laboratories.

**Cat Care**

For those many cats that have survived, their loved ones will want to take care of them as best as possible, but they're still cats with (I assume) cat intelligence.  Litter boxes will become luxurious, cat food will be a little bit more regulated, and cat toys, etc. will be more popular.  Vastly more popular.

**Legislation**

In most countries the treatment of cats will become more strict.  Imagine a disgruntled husband who could finally euthanize his wife with impunity?  That is akin to murder.  Imagine a municipality that generally rounds up cats.  This will change.

**Dogs**

Will suddenly become less popular pets.

**Not Caring**

The level of "not caring" on Earth will increase dramatically, because cats, well, frankly they don't give a damn.

**How did this happen?**

I haven't a clue, but I am looking at my cat right now, who adores and disdains me, and I suspect the cats did it.

Comment: i love that last bit

Answer (score 1):

There is a significant increase in the number of cats and reduction in the human population. Humanity ends.

Unless, since this is world building:

In vitro wombs are very close to being ready. Cloning tech is not really as close as many want to believe, but in a wacky alternate world where this could happen? Could involve higher primates if you wanted to.

Some fertility goddess is willing to make a man bear a child.

Someone recreates woman. This could be magic or science fiction and almost even fact. If she is at all scientifically normal, she'll grow up as one of, if not the most precious being on the planet, mostly based on how many exist. 
That may mean spoiled rotten or highly regimented and controlled and possibly both.

Failing to see any such alternatives, you can assume far higher mortality in the very young, reducing the upper limit of survival. A century out, and all that's left is one or two really old guys without anyone carrying for them, say best.

Comment: +1 for summoning the fertility goddess.  That's some nice out of the box thinking!